# how to slowly display circles one by one?

Tags: java, android

I am new to coding. I am writing a practice app and trying to make it display circles one by one on screen. here is my code below. but it only can display all the circles together at one time. How can I fix it?

```
public class DrawCircle extends View
{
Paint p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
int color;
int x=0;
int y=0;
int r=0;
int n=0;

public DrawCircle(Context con, AttributeSet attr)
{
    super(con,attr);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas c)
{
    super.onDraw(c);
    try
    {
        while(n<10)
        {
            gen();
            p.setColor(color);
            p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            c.drawCircle(x, y, r, p);
            Thread.sleep(100);
            n++;
        }
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void gen()
{
    color = Color.rgb(rand(0,255),rand(0,255),rand(0,255));
    x=rand(0,1200);
    y=rand(0,1200);
    r=rand(50,150);
}

public int rand(int a, int b)
{
    return((int)((b-a+1)*Math.random() + a));
}
}
```

Comment: You would need to use a timer of some type.

Answer (score 1):

You are using one paint object. Can you change your code to initialise paint inside the while loop:

```
while(n<10)
        {
            gen();
            p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);//ADD THIS LINE HERE
            p.setColor(color);
            p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            c.drawCircle(x, y, r, p);
            Thread.sleep(100);
            n++;
        }
```

Comment: a warning shows up  "Avoid object allocations during draw/layout operations (preallocate and reuse instead) " and still can't display circles slowly one by one.